# If $f(z)$ is analytic inside and on the circle $|z| = 2$, is $\oint_{|z|=2}f(z) = 0?$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, analytic-functions

I know if $f$ is analytic in a simply connected domain D then for any closed loop in D this integral is 0. Is that enough to say yes to this question?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$ Actually, it is sufficient to assume that $f$ is continuous on $|z|=2$ and holomorphic inside the circle.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that analytic at a point is equivalent to being differentiable on a neighbourhood of that point. In other words, analyticity is more of a property of open regions of points, rather than just the point itself. So, if you say $f$ is analytic on and in a circle, you are also forcing it to be analytic just outside the circle too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, since the closed disk centered at $0$ with radius $2$ is simply connected.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't domains defined to be open sets in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes. But when we say that $f$ is analytic and its domain $D$ is not an open set, then what that means is that $f$ is the restriction to $D$ of some analytic function whose domain is an open set $A$ which contains $D$. And, if $D$ is a closed disk, then $A$ will contain an open disk with the same center as $D$ and a larger radius.